# Import js file from node module with React

Tags: reactjs, npm, import, geojson

I try to add the **geojson npm package** [@mapbox/togeojson](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mapbox/togeojson).
But i can not use it in my **React app**. I'm a React/Node beginner, sorry!
First, i ran `npm install --save togeojson` to install the module and it's well install in `node_module` folder.
Then, in the React module i try to import geojson.

```
import togeojson from '@mapbox/togeojson';
```

And use it:

```
console.log(togeojson); //undefined
var geoJSON = toGeoJSON.gpx(e.target.result);
```

Comment: Have you tried `import togeojson from 'togeojson';`?

Comment: Yes. I also tried `import togeojson from '@mapbox/togeojson';` but i faced this error: `Module not found: Can't resolve 'togeojson'`.

Comment: Did you restart your local server? Most times you need to do that when updating your package.json file.

Comment: Default export in @mapbox/togeojson seems to be an object and not undefined, check out [a codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/j3jz1r9qxw). Could you please improve the question so we understand the issue better?

Comment: @seanulus: It works after restarting. No need to import!

Comment: Awesome. Glad to help.